# How to use nodejs cuid module?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to generate a token using cuid module located at https://github.com/dilvie/cuid

When I try the following:

```
require('cuid');
var test = cuid();
console.log(test);
```

I get:

```
var test = cuid();
           ^
ReferenceError: cuid is not defined
```

I have made sure I do an npm install cuid prior to running the code.

Can someone advise on what I am missing?

Answer (score 3):

You need to store the function exported by the cuid module to a variable. E.g:

```
var cuid = require('cuid');
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried that too, but it still does not work.  I ended up plucking the relevant code into its own file: